# Can't share an mp3 file. share_plus

Tags: flutter, package, mp3, share, share-plus

I am trying to share a mp3 file with share_plus package. But whenever I try to press the share button, I am getting this error:

```
E/flutter ( 5629): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Share callback error, prior share-sheet did not call back, did you await it? Maybe use non-result variant, null, null)
```

I am already awaiting the process. And here is my code:

```
 onPressed: () async {
                        await Share.shareXFiles([XFile('assets/0.mp3')]);
                      }
```

Comment: try adding this to issues of the package